# Angular UI Datepicker date style

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I want to use Angular UI Datepicker to let the users pick their booking dates and show them,  which dates are available.
So I have to get controle for styling each dates background, with different images.
Is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

**Angularjar UI datepicker dates with images**

angularjs UI datepicker has limited feature as given in documentation .https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
```

your question is great thinking. i had tried to find plugins . but not available. i given below some links it may help you

http://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/Date%20Picker/

http://angularscript.com/collection/date-picker/

http://jsfiddle.net/reLBD/

http://codecanyon.net/item/booking-calendar-pro-jquery-plugin/full_screen_preview/244645

http://www.webdesignbooth.com/jquery-calendar-and-date-picker-plugins/

http://luisfarzati.github.io/ng-bs-daterangepicker/

http://rawgit.com/jdewit/ez-datetime/master/demo.html

https://github.com/spongessuck/gm.datepickerMultiSelect

http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#multidate

Answer (score 0):

As of today, there is a good example in the [documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#datepicker) of **angular-ui** that showcases how to highlight single days. They are using the `$scope.events` array to apply custom styles to individual events (*in this case they style tomorrow and the day after tomorrow*):

```
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
var afterTomorrow = new Date(tomorrow);
afterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
$scope.events = [
  {
    date: tomorrow,
    status: 'full'
  },
  {
    date: afterTomorrow,
    status: 'partially'
  }
];
```

The `status` attribute corresponds to a CSS class that you can define yourself to style the events as desired:

Again, here is an example:

```
<style>
  .full button span {
    background-color: limegreen;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
  .partially button span {
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
</style>
```

If you want to use background images to highlight days, you can apply them in the CSS code using the `background-image` property:

```
.my-event button {
  background-image: url('/path/to/your/image.png');
}
```

I'm not sure, though, how the calendar will look with images. You probably need to apply further attributes to adjust the image's position and background repeat. But in general, this should get you set on how to style dates individually.